# Variable in for loop is giving a message that "The value of the local variable i is not used"

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, local-variables, private-methods

I wrote a for loop that is supposed to determine if there is user input. If there is, it sets the 6 elements of `int[] valueArr` to the input, a vararg `int[] statValue`. If there is no input, it sets all elements equal to -1.

```
if (statValue.length == 6) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        valueArr[i] = statValue[i];
    }

} else {
    for (int i : valueArr) {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code, and it is giving me a message in `for (int i : valueArr)` :

> "The value of the local variable i is not used."

That particular for loop syntax is still new to me, so I may be very well blind, but it was working in another file:

```
for(int i : rollResults) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

I feel that I should also mention that the for loop giving me trouble is in a `private void` method. I'm still fairly new and just recently started using private methods. I noticed the method would give the same message when not used elsewhere, but I do not see why it would appear here.

I tried closing and reopening Visual Studio Code, deleting and retyping the code, and other forms of that. In my short experience, I've had times where I received errors and messages that should not be there and fixed them with what I mentioned, but none of that worked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```java
> for (int i : valueArr) {
>  .... CODE HERE ...
> }
> ```

This sets up a loop which will run `CODE HERE` a certain number of times. Inside this loop, at the start of every loop, an entirely new variable is created named `i`, containing one of the values in `valueArr`. *Once the loop ends this variable **is destroyed***. Notably, `i` is *not* directly the value in `valueArr` - modifying it **does nothing** - other than affect this one loop if you use `i` later in within the block. It *does not* modify the contents of `valueArr`.

Hence why you get the warning: `i = -1` does nothing - you change what `i` is, and then the loop ends, which means `i` **goes away** and your code hasn't changed anything or done anything, which surely you didn't intend. Hence, warning.

It's not entirely clear what you want to do here. If you intend to set all values in `valueArr` to -1, you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valueArr.length; i++) valueArr[i] = -1;
```

Or, actually, you can do that more simply:

```
Arrays.fill(valueArr, -1);
```

`valueArr[i] = -1` changes the value of the `i`-th value in the `valueArr` array to `-1`. `for (int i : valueArr) i = -1;` does *nothing*.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware it destroyed the variable, but that does make sense now considering it is instantiated in the loop.